# Error while installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a netbook via USB. I've created an USB image with the GTK utility that comes with Ubuntu.

When I try to boot it up, it shows an error message:

```
ERROR: No configuration file found
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
```

And a prompt that says

```
boot:
```

Can you help me?

Comment: try `mboot.c32 -c boot.cfg` at the boot command.

Comment: Sometimes, creating the USB drive does not work flawlessly. If you think this might be the case, try to run the procedure to create a bootable USB stick again. After creating, but before disconnecting, run `sync` in terminal to ensure that all data is actually written and wait with disconnecting until that command has finished.

Comment: Sorry, but my problem has changed now. When I saw your answer, I created a boot USB again, and now it magically boots up. But I get a BusyBox v1.19.3 prompt. It says: "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system".

Comment: Well, I did what soulsource said and my problem became the first again, so I tried the command @Projjol said, and now it says: "Could not find kernel image: mboot.c32"

Answer (score 0):

Upon further reading one solution that pops up quite often is this-

1. Rename the `isolinux` folder to `syslinux`
2. In the same folder, rename the files `isolinux.bin` and `isolinux.cfg`to `syslinux.bin` and `syslinux.cfg`, respectively.

Give installation a shot after these changes.

Comment: There was already a directory called syslinux and in the same directory, a file called syslinux.cfg; however there was a file called isolinux.bin which I renamed to syslinux.bin. It didn't work again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Finally, I could install Linux Mint.